# VBA - Return Results in Sheet 2 if Sheet 1 is full

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm currently running a SQL stored procedure from an Excel Macro.  The count of returned records exceeds the maximum rows for one sheet.  How can I transfer the overflow results to a second sheet?

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim par As String
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."

' Remove any values in the cells where we
' want to put our Stored Procedure's results.
Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.ClearContents


' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=67.09;Initial Catalog=TEST..."
 cmd.ActiveConnection = con

 Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."
cmd.CommandText = "SP_Billing"
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

' Copy the results to cell B7 on the first Worksheet
Set WSP1 = Worksheets(1)
WSP1.Activate
If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(8, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully updated."
End Sub
```

Comment: try using objRecordset.MoveNext and keep track of which cell you are writing to all withing a Do While Not rs.EOF Loop

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `MaxRows` parameter to [.CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx) and loop until you hit `EOF`.  Each call advances the cursor in the recordset, and the copy starts from the current cursor location.  I'd extract it to a `Sub` something like...

```vb
Private Sub SplitRecordsToSheets(records As ADODB.Recordset, perSheet As Long)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Do While Not records.EOF
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        ws.Cells(8, 2).CopyFromRecordset records, perSheet
    Loop
End Sub
```

...and then call it like this:

```vb
' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=67.09;Initial Catalog=TEST..."
cmd.ActiveConnection = con

Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."
cmd.CommandText = "SP_Billing"
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

SplitRecordsToSheets rs, ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require some custom handling while parsing through your RecordSet (such as switching pages once you have printed, say 100k rows), you can no longer use the `Range.CopyFromRecordset` method.  Instead, you may have to iterate through the recordset yourself.  Here is a small sample of how to do such a thing (without giving the whole puzzle away, of course:

```
Dim i_RowCount As Long
Dim a_PrintArray As Variant, rg_PrintRg As Range
Dim i_Col As Integer
Const i_MaxRows As Long = 100000
' I recommend filling everything into an Array first and then Printing the array to Excel'

' Using your existing variables also '
ReDim a_PrintArray( 1 to i_MaxRows, 1 to rs.Fields.Count )
Set sh_Current = WSP1
Do Until rs.EOF
    i_RowCount = i_RowCount + 1

    If i_RowCount > i_MaxRows Then 'If we hit the max, print what we have'
        ' Setting up the print range to match the array size '
        Set rg_PrintRg = shCurrent.Cells(8, 2)
        Set rg_PrintRg = Range(rg_PrintRg, rg_PrintRg.Offset(i_MaxRows - 1, rs.Fields.Count - 1))
        rg_PrintRg = a_PrintArray  ' Print the array into the range '
        i_RowCount = 1
        Set sh_Current = sh_Current.Next
        ReDim a_PrintArray( 1 to i_MaxRows, 1 to rs.Fields.Count )
    End If

    For i_Col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1        
        a_PrintArray(i_RowCount, i_Col) = rs.Fields(i_Col).Value
    Next i_Col

    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Please note this code snippit is for demonstration only.  It has not been compiled and may not be optimal for your specific application.  For more information on the Recordset object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx